# Post Increment Evaluation i + i++ + i + i++;

Tags: java, increment, decrement

I am going through *Increment Operator* and *Decrement Operator*, but stuck with the logic of this problem.

```
class Demo {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    i= 0, j= 0;  
    j = i + i++ + i + i++;

System.out.println("i="+i);
System.out.println("j="+j);

}
}
```

How do I evaluate this?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Not again - Have you done a search - besides if you write code that you have difficultly reading what do you expect?!

Comment: in `C` `+` is not a sequence point, so it is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java has a left-to-right guaranteed evaluation order and this means that

```
j = i + i++ + i + i++;
```

evaluates as (in sequence)

```
i      // 0
i++    // 0 (and i becomes 1)
i      // 1
i++    // 1 (and i becomes 2)
```

thus the answer will be 2, 2

Comment: But when I tried to evaluate this expression I am confused                                                                                                       int i = 0, j = 1;                                                                                                int k = i + j++ + ++i + ++j + i++;                                                                 How do I arrive at output i = 2,  j = 3, k = 6

Comment: int i = 0, j = 1;
int k = i + j++ + ++i + ++j + i++; 

i    // 0
j++  // 1  (and j becomes 2)
++i  // 1
++j  // 3  (and j becomes 3)
i++  // 1

0 1 1 3 1